# -[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets] stretching wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiedgeinsets

So, I have a `.png` image that is (640, 960) pixels in dimension. I'm trying to create a resizable image from the `.png` in order to stretch that image vertically and fit an iPhone 5's (640, 1096) pixel view.

I'm loading the image using `+[UIImage imageNamed:]`, which is works fine. I then create a resizable image via `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]` using (480, 320, 479, 320) insets.

I then set the image to `UIImageView`. On an iPhone 4 & 4S it looks great (duh). On an iPhone 5, it appears to simply stretch the whole image vertically to 1096px, completely ignoring cap insets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, when you're using a (640, 960) pixel image, it needs to be an `@2x.png`.

Also, @bill-williams project was super helpful: https://github.com/asmallteapot/ImageStretchDemo